# Xpath assign single table name to multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is the code from which I'm trying to extract some values to file.

```
<div class="Header">

    <h1 class="tname">Table#1</h1>

    <div class="in_table">
         <tr>
                <td>Value1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>Value2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td>Value2</td>
         </tr>
          
    </div>
</div>
```

So my xpath looks like

```
//div[@class='in_table']/tr[position()>1]|//div[@class='Header']/h1
```

But it gives me only one table name on the top and the rest of the values below. My target is to get each value with assigned table name.
Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Not possible with XPath 1.0, AFAICS

Comment: Can you show an example output of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Table#1 | Value1 / Table#1 | Value2 / Table#1 | Value3

Comment: you many need to use xquery